# Django blog comments

Tags: django, forms, model, comments, rendering

I can't get to add the new comment in the list of existing commetns on a post. Here's the model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commented_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Commented by {self.commented_by} on {self.post}.'
```

Here's the view:

```
def post_detail(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    comments = post.comments.all().order_by('-commented_on')
    total_comments = post.comments.all().count()
    form = CommentForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.post = post
            instance.save()

    context = {
        'post' : post,
        'comments' : comments,
        'form' : form,
        'total_comments' : total_comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are passing wrong model instance to the Form when you are trying to save a new comment:

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=post)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Actually there is no need to do that, you can simply declare the form instance by:

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST)
```

Here is a minor refactored code:

```
def post_detail(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.post = post
            # instance.comment_by = request.user
            instance.save()
    comments = post.comments.all().order_by('-commented_on')
    total_comments = comments.count()
    context = {
        'post' : post,
        'comments' : comments,
        'form' : form,
        'total_comments' : total_comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: How does writing the comments variable and total_comments after the form help ?

Comment: Then your form is not validating. See here on how to display form error: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages